# What's the difference between Git bash and WSL

Tags: bash, git, git-bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just installed Git SCM on my Windows machine. My machine had Node installed earlier. I am able to use node -v in git bash. But, Why I am able to use windows applications inside Git Bash and not in WSL Bash.

Inside WSL Bash-

```
hello@comp:~$ node -v

Command 'node' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install nodejs
```

Inside Git Bash-

```
hello@comp MINGW64 
$ node -v
v12.10.0
```

Answer (score 10):

WSL is an a Linux like compatibility layer. You run Linux applications on top of WSL and they think they are running natively on Linux while the system calls are being translated to Windows OS system calls (WSL2 -- not yet released -- is a full Linux kernel running inside Windows). You do get to access Windows files through /mnt/c/... but that's about all you can expect in terms of Windows-Linux interoperability.

Git-bash, on the other hand, is a *Windows* app -- a shell running windows applications. Some of these may be compiled with a Linux compatibility *library* (Cygwin). But they don't have to be. This provides a less "Linux-like" experience but may be a good compromise if all you want are some Linux command line tools and don't need to install full-blown Linux executables.

Comment: Any idea of what the difference in performance is between Git-bash, WSL, WSL2 and DOS window? Would like to do Data Science with command line but not sure which one to go for in terms of speed.

Comment: Haven't tested so no idea. File access performance under WSL (and probably WSL2 to some extent) is in my experience significantly worse than native Windows apps. However, lots of data science tools just load the data and manipulate it in memory most of the time. So perhaps it's not a big issue. Go with WSL2 if you need Linux tools or just install python as a native Windows executable if not.

Answer (score 2):

Definition of PATH for both "environments" is different. Check that node's dir shows up on Git bash's and not in WSL Bash. Run this on both environments:

```
echo $PATH
```